# Adjusting column width within sas

Tags: sas

Often this happens alot when I run sas programs where the column does not display the full text. For example

[image]

[image]

The column status does not display the entire statement 'Not so Good'. What can I do to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't assigned the longest value the first time the variable 'Status' is assigned, it was truncated in your DATA step. You need to add to your DATA step

```
length Status $ 11;
```

Further information is provided here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001336069.htm